# In JavaScript , how does one use the __proto__ property to create more objects?

Tags: javascript, prototype

According to the Caja paper:

> **Forbidden names.** In Firefox, access to the "__proto__" property of an
>   object would grant the authority to create more objects like it, which
>   violates the principle of least authority. Therefore, Caja rejects all
>   names ending with " __ " (double underscore). This also gives the Caja
>   implementation a place to store its book- keeping information where it
>   is invisible to the Caja programmer.

I tried in Firebug, just seeing all the methods  `__proto__` has(i.e., `pkcsll, atob, btoa, screenX` etc), but I don't see a copy-type method. How is `__proto__` exploited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't call it an exploit exactly but, in a JavaScript engine that supports `__proto__`, you can create an object with the same prototype as any object by the following,

```
function makeObjectLike(a) {
    function maker() { }
    maker.prototype = a.__proto__;
    return new maker();
}
```

You can also do the same thing using ES5's `Object.getPrototypeOf(a)` instead of `a.__proto__`.

Caja prohibits things not because they are intrinsicly bad but because they could be used for evil if you don't trust the code you are loading and running. Using this technique is just fine in your own code (except for browser compatibility issues).

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm not getting what they're saying, you don't need `__proto__` to create more objects from the same prototype of the original.

You can do that with standard ecmascript 5 methods.

```
function FooBar() {}
FooBar.prototype.foo = function() { return "bar"; };

 /* create a FooBar object */
var fb1 = new FooBar();



 /* using __proto__ this creates an object with the same prototype as fb1 */    
var fb2 = {};
fb2.__proto__ = fb1.__proto__;



 /* and so does this, but without __proto__ */
var fb3 = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(fb1));



fb1 instanceof FooBar; // true
fb2 instanceof FooBar; // true
fb3 instanceof FooBar; // true
```